# Dynamically create define in a PROC REPORT

Tags: sas

I have a dataset(`liste_institution`) that contain all the name of the variable that I want to "`define`" in my `proc report` statement. Here is my code that work when I call my macro not dynamically(`%create_institution(815);`). If I use the data statement with the call execute(in comment in my code) it not working. The reason seem to be that when I use the call execute the code is not interpreted in a PROC REPORT that is why it give me error.

```
proc report data =  ventes_all_inst4
                            missing split = "*" nowd
                            style(header)=[font_weight=bold background = #339966 foreground = white]
                            style(column)=[cellwidth=15cm];

    %macro create_institution(institution);

        define TOTAL_&institution. / display "TOTAL*($)" style(column)=[cellwidth=4cm];

    %mend;
            /* Give error when I use this data step */
            /*data _null_;
                set liste_institution;
                call execute('%create_institution(' || INS || ');');
            run;*/
            %create_institution(815);

run;
```

Is there an easy way to create dynamically define statement in a PROC REPORT from a dataset that contain the column name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you have a misunderstanding of how macros work and timing.  You need to compile the macro list previous to the proc report, but you can't use `call execute` because that actually executes code.  You need to create a macro variable.

Easiest way to do it is like so:

```
proc sql;
  select cats('%create_institution(',ins,')')
    into :inslist separated by ' '
    from liste_institution
  ;
quit;
```

which makes `&inslist` which is now the list of institutions (with the macro call).

You also may be able to use `across` variables to allow this to be easier; what you'd have is one row per `ins`, with a single variable with that value (which defines the column name) and another single variable with the value that goes in the data table portion.  Then SAS will automatically create columns for each `across` value. Across variables are one of the things that makes `proc report` extremely powerful.

Comment: The `call execute` approach is not impossible, but you would need to generate the entire `proc report` block in your data step, not just the repetitive bits. Joe's approach is fine as long as you don't hit the macro variable character limit.

Comment: I didn't bother mentioning that because I'd be veeeeeery afraid of a report that had enough 25-character-at-a-time columns to hit that limit ;)

Comment: It work thank you , the only thing now is the proc sql statement give me error again like if SAS trying to interpret the code put it work perfectly when I call my macro variable in my proc report!

Comment: I found why I still have an error in because my variable "INS" is numeric. I just convert "INS" to string and it work perfectly with no error thank you again!